# ApnsPHP: utf-8 and "Internal error" when push?

Tags: php, ios, apple-push-notifications, apns-php

after the translation of website to utf-8, push no longer sent
it gets when i send push: *"Internal error (127 by written in instead of 105 bytes)"*

If I try to send in Latin, i received 3 same push-es (i test it on my iphone) and writes its an error.

If I try to send a Cyrillic symbols at UTF-8, then I get an error and the push does not come.

If in the Push.php file I change the line

```
$nLen = strlen ($aMessage ['BINARY_NOTIFICATION']);
```

to `$nLen = mb_strlen($aMessage ['BINARY_NOTIFICATION'], 'latin1');`
push in Latin comes successfully and there are no errors

Cyrillic does not come (but does not show errors)

```
$ nLen = mb_strlen ($ aMessage ['BINARY_NOTIFICATION'], 'utf-8');
```

Does not help. how to be?

Comment: Can you explain which parts of that code cause the error? Additionally, which language is used? `$ nLen = mb_strlen construction` is no valid PHP code

Comment: There are same problem, but decided for latin  https://github.com/immobiliare/ApnsPHP/issues/88

Comment: I have russian letters

Comment: And error not by code. Error - result of code, pushes with russian letters don't send